# Check if two pyspark Rows are equal

Tags: python, python-2.7, unit-testing, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am writing unit tests for a Spark job, and some of the outputs are named tuples: `pyspark.sql.Row`

How can I assert their equality?

```
actual = get_data(df)
expected = Row(total=4, unique_ids=2)
self.assertEqual(actual, expected)
```

When I do this, the values are rearranged in an order I can not determine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work as written because according to the [docs](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row):

> the fields will be sorted by names.

Nevertheless, another way is to use the [`asDict()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.Row.asDict) method of the `pySpark.sql.Row` and compare them as dictionaries:

```python
actual = get_data(df)
expected = Row(total=4, unique_ids=2)
self.assertEqual(actual.asDict(), expected.asDict())
```