# pyspark.sql.types.Row to list

Tags: python, pyspark

My initial data set are:

```
{'ID': [Row(userid=17562323, gross_merchandise_value=6072210944, country=u'ID'), Row(userid=29989283, gross_merchandise_value=4931252224, country=u'ID')]
```

the type of dict value is `pyspark.sql.types.Row`

How to convert the dict to the userid list? like below:

```
[17562323, 29989283],
```

just get the userid list.

Comment: I think you have an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/39467501/2799214

Comment: Related/possible dupes: [Convert rows into Dictionary in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49432573/5858851), [Collecting the result of PySpark Dataframe filter into a variable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49430020/5858851), and [Check if two pyspark Rows are equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49519475/check-if-two-pyspark-rows-are-equal/49521096#49521096)

Comment: TL;DR: You can access the elements of a `pyspark.sql.Row` like you would for a dictionary. So in your case you want `[value['userid'] for value in myDict['ID']]`

Comment: May be easier to read the rdd directly: `df.rdd.map(lambda r: row.userid).collect()`

Comment: thank you above all,the problem solved.I use ***.asDict()['userid'] for old_row_list to get the new userid list

Answer (score 5, accepted):

thank you above all,the problem solved.I use row_ele.asDict()['userid'] in **old_row_list** to get the **new_userid_list**